# Regex for replacing all trailing zeroes with nines

Tags: regex, biginteger

I'm trying to implement BigInt subtract one, and want to optimize my code. Right now I just iterate over the number string, e.g. "1241241291919191904124142398623500000000000000" and in order to subtract one, all the trailing zeroes need to be replaced with nines.

How would I do this with regex?

What is a smart way to use regex to implement the BigInt subtractOne(string) function? It has a couple special cases.

This is what I have so far to match the trailing zeroes:

```
m = re.search('(?<=[1-9])0+$', '91000')
```

Comment: regex in this case are less "optimized" than just scanning by "hand" from the last char of the string back to the first non-zero digit. The negative look-behind should sound like: match any number of 0 "tied" to the end, which are preceded by a non zero digit. The regex looks ok

Comment: @John the positive lookbehind is not needed, `0+$` will match all trailing 0. The problem is that regex can not replace them with the same amount of nines directly. Which language are you using?

Comment: You do know that this is a problematic way to do substraction? When are you going to decrement the digit before the string of zeroes? Before? Then you'd get `10 - 1 = 99`. After? Then you'd get `290 - 1 = 199`.

Comment: I've thrown my vote in with @TimPietzcker's answer, but it should be noted that the pattern you're asking for only works for subtracting 1 from a **positive** number evenly divisible by 10.

Comment: Also, I hope you're doing this purely as a programming exercise. You do know that Python does BigInts right out of the box, right?

Answer (score 2):

Use a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
import re
s =  "1241241291919191904124142398623500000000000000"
r = re.compile("""0       # Match 0
                  (?=     # only if the following can be matched here:
                   0*     # zero or more 0s
                   $      # until the end of the string.
                  )       # End of lookahead assertion""", re.VERBOSE)
```

Now you can do

```
>>> r.sub("9", s)
'1241241291919191904124142398623599999999999999'
```

Comment: @Kaz: That was not the question. This is only about how to change all trailing zeroes into nines.

Answer (score 1):

The other possibility then would be to use a function that returns the replacement

```
import re

def ReplZeros(matchobj):
    return len(matchobj.group(0)) * "9"

text = '1241241291919191904124142398623500000000000000'
res = re.sub(r'0+$', ReplZeros, text)

print text
print res
```

Output

> 1241241291919191904124142398623500000000000000
>   1241241291919191904124142398623599999999999999